# Bounded expectation of a martingale process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, expectation, martingales, poisson-process

Suppose $N(t)$ is a rate $\lambda$ Poisson process. I define $X(t) = N(t) - \lambda t$. I need to argue that $\mathbb{E}[|X(t)|]< \infty$. I would proceed as follows
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[|X(t)|] = \mathbb{E}[|N(t) - \lambda t|] \le \mathbb{E}[ N(t) + \lambda t] = 2 \lambda t,
\end{align}
So it is clearly bounded in expectation for **finite** times $t<\infty$. But is this argument sufficient to establish boundedness of $|X(t)|$ in expectation? I would appreciate any insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it suffices. The target $\mathbb{E}\left|X_t\right|<\infty$ means exactly that, for each given $t$, $\mathbb{E}\left|X_t\right|$ is a finite value; it does not mean that $\mathbb{E}\left|X_t\right|$ is uniformly bounded by all $t\ge 0$.

In fact, note that
$$
\mathbb{E}\left|N_t-\lambda t\right|
$$
is the [mean deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_absolute_deviation) of $N_t$.

Provided that
$$
N_t\sim\text{Poiss}(\lambda t),
$$
we have, by referring to [this table](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MeanDeviation.html) if you do not want to carry out the details of the calculation,
$$
\mathbb{E}\left|N_t-\lambda t\right|=\frac{2}{\lfloor\lambda t\rfloor!}\left(\lambda t\right)^{\lfloor\lambda t\rfloor+1}e^{-\lambda t},
$$
where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ denotes the largest integer smaller than or equal to $x$.

With this exact value of $\mathbb{E}\left|X_t\right|$, you may see that as $t\to\infty$, $\mathbb{E}\left|X_t\right|\to\infty$.

Comment: Thanks for the clear and detailed explanation. So, in this case the mean deviation is bounded in expectation which suffices for the continuous-time martingale property (right?); but it is not uniformly bounded by all $t\ge 0$, is that the right way to put it?

Comment: @user2348674: No problem. Yes for both questions. $N_t-\lambda t$ in this case becomes a continuous-time martingale.